# Entry in database not being overwritten when looking at ID

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently looking at a script that a previous developer made that is meant to look a table, if the id does not exist then create the new code, if it does exist, overwrite the existing one.

Sounds fairly simple, but I can't get my head around how Yii manages the overwrite and new verification code. It is only adding new records, not over writing.

```
  $invitingUser = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);

        if ($invitingUser->isAttending($eventId)) {
            // Event attending
            $event = Event::model()->findByPk($eventId);

            // 
            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            $this->performAjaxValidation(array($guestInviteForm));

            if (isset($_POST['GuestInviteForm'])) {
                $guestInviteForm->attributes = $_POST['GuestInviteForm'];

                // Perform Validation
                $valid = $guestInviteForm->validate();

                if ($valid) {
                    // Check if a Verification Code entry for this user already exists
                    $existingVerificationCode = VerificationCode::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id' => $user->user_id, 'type' => VerificationCode::TYPE_GUEST_INVITE));


                   //THE CODE ONLY SEEMS TO RUN THIS. 
                    if (is_null($existingVerificationCode)) {
                        // Create Verification Code instance
                        $verificationCode = new VerificationCode();
                        $verificationCode->type = VerificationCode::TYPE_GUEST_INVITE;
                        $verificationCode->user_id = $invitingUser->id;
                        $verificationCode->verification_code = VerificationCode::generateVerificationCode();
                        $verificationCode->forename = $guestInviteForm->forename;
                        $verificationCode->surname = $guestInviteForm->surname;
                        $verificationCode->event_id = $eventId;

                        $verificationCode->save(false);
                    } else {
                        // Update existing Verification Code enty
                        $existingVerificationCode->type = VerificationCode::TYPE_GUEST_INVITE;
                        $existingVerificationCode->user_id = $invitingUser->id;
                        $existingVerificationCode->forename = $guestInviteForm->forename;
                        $existingVerificationCode->surname = $guestInviteForm->surname;
                        $code = $existingVerificationCode->verification_code = VerificationCode::generateVerificationCode();
                        $existingVerificationCode->save(false);
                    }
```

The code never seems to enter the else here

```
//THE CODE ONLY SEEMS TO RUN THIS. 
                        if (is_null($existingVerificationCode)) {
                            // Create Verification Code instance
                            $verificationCode = new VerificationCode();
                            $verificationCode->type = VerificationCode::TYPE_GUEST_INVITE;
                            $verificationCode->user_id = $invitingUser->id;
                            $verificationCode->verification_code = VerificationCode::generateVerificationCode();
                            $verificationCode->forename = $guestInviteForm->forename;
                            $verificationCode->surname = $guestInviteForm->surname;
                            $verificationCode->event_id = $eventId;

                            $verificationCode->save(false);
                        } else {
                            // Update existing Verification Code enty
                            $existingVerificationCode->type = VerificationCode::TYPE_GUEST_INVITE;
                            $existingVerificationCode->user_id = $invitingUser->id;
                            $existingVerificationCode->forename = $guestInviteForm->forename;
                            $existingVerificationCode->surname = $guestInviteForm->surname;
                            $code = $existingVerificationCode->verification_code = VerificationCode::generateVerificationCode();
                            $existingVerificationCode->save(false);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st. After form validation:

```
if ($valid) {
```

Verification code select done:

```
$existingVerificationCode = VerificationCode::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id' => $user->user_id, 'type' => VerificationCode::TYPE_GUEST_INVITE));
```

If you translate it to SQL it will be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM verification_code WHERE user_id=x AND type=x
```

2nd. Check if record exists

```
if (is_null($existingVerificationCode)) {
```

If its not - creating new, populating, saving.

Else updating:

```
$existingVerificationCode->type = VerificationCode::TYPE_GUEST_INVITE;
$existingVerificationCode->user_id = $invitingUser->id;
$existingVerificationCode->forename = $guestInviteForm->forename;
$existingVerificationCode->surname = $guestInviteForm->surname;
$code = $existingVerificationCode->verification_code = VerificationCode::generateVerificationCode();
$existingVerificationCode->save(false);
```

`save(false)` means save without validation. Consider model attributes - fields in your database table.

Comment: The code never goes into the else though. It only ever creates even if the user_id already exists.

Comment: dump `$existingVerificationCode`, and query compares not only `user_id` it's also depends on `type`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it ever goes in the ELSE because it never finds $existingVerificationCode.

We don't have the whole code, but from what I see, I suspect you're checking the wrong user, because it's weird to search for an event for $user, and if that doesn't exist, to create one related to $invitingUser.

```
$existingVerificationCode = VerificationCode::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id' => $user->user_id, 'type' => VerificationCode::TYPE_GUEST_INVITE));
// ...
$verificationCode->user_id = $invitingUser->id;
```